# Why is it that some shikigami are like Wanzer from Front Mission?

Tags: tokyo-ravens

In Tokyo Ravens, why is it that some of the shikigamis (especially those used by the Onmyou Agency) are looking like wanzer from Front Mission? What is it derived from? Is there any improvement in Onmyouji between the time of the Abe no Senmei and the current time in Tokyo Ravens that caused this? Is there any explanation for this anywhere in the novel or anime?

EDIT: The following link refers to the Shikigami I call "looking like wanzer". http://tokyo-ravens.wikia.com/wiki/Emperor

Comment: Can you put up some screenshot to show the similarity? I can't quite remember, but I don't think they look mecha.

Comment: All giant mechas of a specific type in the Front Mission universe are called [Wanzers](http://frontmission.wikia.com/wiki/Wanzer). Please be more specific.

Comment: That Emperor shikigami doesn't look particularly Wanzer-like to me. Wanzers have a squater stance than it appears to have, and none of the details look like any particular Wanzer design I can find after a quick search. What make you think they resemble Wanzers?